# Profile doesn't match application identifier

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

I have just created a AdHoc distribution provisioning profile for the app id 49776ZQRBG.com.gfeed.ride I have the Bundle ID in the info.plist set to this, yet this provisining profile in the project settings is greyed out and states

"profile doesn't match application identifier '49776ZQRBG.com.gfeed.ride'"

If I look at the profile in the organizer within XCode it gives me the same App Identifier as whats in my plist.

Is there something else I am missing? Is the application identifier different to the bundle identifier?

Comment: it used to be like this: "you must enter com.gfeed.ride in your plist, DO NOT ENTER 49776ZQRBG.com.gfeed.ride"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Usually you would use just "com.gfeed.ride" as your identifier, and XCode will automatically take care of the "49776ZQRBG" part.

Answer (score 6):

When I got this error here is what I missed and corrected.

1. Check that you have your Entitlements.plist file created and configured.
2. Check info.plist and ensure that your application name is correct.

It's probably best to just go through the directions off of the iPhone dev site on apple. Same place you created your provision profiles.

Edit: Came across this on another post on this site. It's a link with more complete instructions than I have time to type.

http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/

Comment: thanks for the response, the above answer worked perfectly, although reading the link in your response gave me a better idea of wats going on ;)

Answer (score 0):

it's bug from Apple, it appears when you add automatically device via Organizer. solution: never add device via Organizer.

Comment: note that this question was asked and fully answered in 2009, next time try to note the post date before answering. Thanks!