# How to match my App's application identifier with provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I just started with iOS and reading the iOS Programing the Big Nerd Ranch Guide book.

The quiz works fine on the Simulator. But when I try running it on my iPhone, it gives me this error message:

> Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the
>   application's Identifier 'com.bignerdranch.Quiz' could not be found

The provisioning profile that was created for me by XCode has an App Identifier TZG8GHST3.* hence shouldn't it just match any bundle identifier by default?
Not really sure how to match them.

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853253/profile-doesnt-match-application-identifier) here, but didn't solve my problem.

An advice would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: sorry could you elaborate a bit more? I don't think I have specified any company name in the dev certificate.  Where can I double check this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle identifier has prefix the `APPID`. In your case your bundle identifier will be `TZG8GHST3`.

So you need to take care of `APPID`.* not the `APPID`. Apple will take care of `APPID` if you manage *

You just need to ensure that you specify a unique Bundle ID in your Xcode project, which will be automatically appended to `AppID`.

Comment: Are saying I should change the Bundle Identifier for my project from `com.bignerdranch.Quiz` to `TZG8GHST3.com.bignerdranch.Quiz` ??

Comment: I ended up going to the `https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile` and download the certificate and make sure its added to my system.  Then I rebuilt without changing anything and it worked. Very strange